# php security should I hide query string in url

Tags: php, mysql, security

A number of my pages are produced from results pulled from MySQL using $_Get. It means the urls end like this `/park.php?park_id=1`. Is this a security issue and would it be better to hide the query string from the URL? If so how do I go about doing it?

Also I have read somewhere that Google doesn't index URLs with a `?`, this would be a problem as these are the main pages of my site. Any truth in this?

Thanks

Comment: It's only a security issue if you don't sanitize/restrict the query params on your side. In other words, check that the value of `park_id` is what you expect before using it in your code...

Comment: If editing the URL allows you to get arbitrary items you shouldn't have access to, the issue is in your server-side code.

Comment: As for the google question see [this guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) (around pages 8-11). **Edit** - answer is Google prefers SEO friendly URL's but will still index query strings.

Comment: Then how do you identify individual parks? You need to pass *some form of id* through the URL for the script to be useful at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only a security concern if this is sensitive information.  For example, you send a user to this URL:

```
/park.php?park_id=1
```

Now the user knows that the park currently being viewed has a system identifier of "1" in the database.  What happens if the user then manually requests this?:

```
/park.php?park_id=2
```

Have they compromised your security?  If they're not *allowed* to view park ID 2 then this request should fail appropriately.  But is it a problem is they happen to *know* that there's an ID of 1 or 2?

In either case, all the user is doing is making a request.  The server-side code is responsible for appropriately handling that request.  If the user is not permitted to view that data, deny the request.  Don't try to stop the user from *making* the request, because they can always find a way.  (They can just manually type it in.  Even without ever having visited your site in the first place.)  The security takes place in responding to the request, not in making it.

There is some data they're not allowed to *know*.  But an ID probably isn't that data.  (Or at least shouldn't be, because numeric IDs are very easy to guess.)

Comment: @HamZa: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you referring to SQL injection?  That's a vulnerability in server-side code (by inappropriately handling the request) and has nothing to do with query string values.  SQL injection can also happen with PUT/POST values, request bodies, etc.  The security problem there isn't that there's a query string value, but that there's bad code on the server.

Comment: Yes I'm referring to SQL injection, well it was just my expectations. Don't get me wrong, your answer is good.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is absolutely no truth to it.

ANY data that comes from a client is subject to spoofing. No matter if it's in a query string, or a POST form or URL. It's as simple as that...

As far as "Google doesn't index URLs with a `?`", who-ever told you that has no clue what they are talking about. There are "SEO" best practices, but they have nothing to do with "google doesn't index". It's MUCH more fine grained than that. And yes, Google will index you just fine.

@David does show one potential issue with using an identifier in a URL. In fact, this has a very specific name: [**A4: Insecure Direct Object Reference**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

Note that it's not *that* using the ID is bad. It's that you need to authorize the user for the URL. So doing permissions soley by the links you show the user is **BAD**. But if you also authorize them when hitting the URL, you should be fine.

So no, in short, you're fine. You can go with "pretty urls", but don't feel that you have to because of anything you posted here...